# recursion functional programming dilemma

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, functional-programming

Below is my code in JavaScript. The loop answer down at the bottom is      the correct answer.

My recursion version is incorrect and it is so illogical that when the index is 3 and the array length is 3 that the computer still enter the if statment... why? If 3 is not less than 3, the computer should not enter that if statement. help me fix the recursion answer. The loop is correct and fine and should be left alone.

```
var data = [
   { 
      name: "Jamestown",
     population: 2047,
     temperatures: [-34, 67, 101, 87]
   },
 {
   name: "Awesome Town",
   population: 3568,
   temperatures: [-3, 4, 9, 12]
 },
{
  name: "Funky Town",
  population: 1000000,
  temperatures: [75, 75, 75, 75, 75]
}
];
```

recursion answer

```
function john( arr, i, j, total, coord)
{

   var total = total || 0;
   var coord = coord || [];

  if(i < arr.length)
  {

   if(j < arr[i].temperatures.length)
   {
     total = arr[i].temperatures[j] + total;
     john(arr, i, j + 1, total, coord)
   }

     ave = total / arr[i].temperatures.length;
     total = 0;
     coord.push([ave, arr[i].population])

     john(arr, i + 1, 0, total, coord)

    }
    return coord;
  }

console.log("recursion answer(it is wrong) is")
console.log( john(data, 0, 0, 0))
```

loop answer

```
var coords = [],
   totalTemperature = 0,
   averageTemperature = 0;

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  totalTemperature = 0;

 for (var j=0; j < data[i].temperatures.length; j++) {
   totalTemperature += data[i].temperatures[j];
 }

  averageTemperature = totalTemperature / data[i].temperatures.length;

  coords.push([averageTemperature, data[i].population]);
}

console.log("correct answer is this loop answer ...")
console.log(coords)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: run my entire code and u see what i mean

Comment: Using correct grammar will help communication a lot, but no, I don't see what you mean. You didn't answer my question.

Comment: squint, good job for editing because i suk at editing for stackoverflow to post the question. sorry for the confusion. i knew someday i will get in trouble with using "return <recursion function name>" or just "<recursion function name>". so today is the day it happen

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace a nested loop with two recursive calls to the same function.

When you call the function with `i, j + 1` it won't just do the calls for the following values for `j`, it will also do the calls for the following values for `i`. When you call it with `i + 1, j` it won't just do the calls for the following vales for `i`, it will also do the calls for the following values for `j`.

Instead of getting a chain of calls that looks like this:

```
0,0
  0,1
    0,2
      0,3
  1,0
    1,1
      1,2
        1,3
    2,0
      2,1
        2,2
          2,3
            2,4
```

You get something that looks like this:

```
0,0
  0,1
    0,2
      0,3
        0,4
          1,0
            1,1
              1,2
                1,3
                  2,0
                    2,1
                      2,2
                        2,3
                          2,4
                2,0
                  2,1
                    2,2
                      2,3
                        2,4
              2,0
                2,1
                  2,2
                    2,3
                      2,4
            2,0
              2,1
                2,2
                  2,3
                    2,4
        1,0
          1,1
            1,2
              1,3
                2,0
                  2,1
                    2,2
                      2,3
                        2,4
              2,0
                2,1
                  2,2
                    2,3
                      2,4
            2,0
              2,1
                2,2
                  2,3
                    2,4
          2,0
            2,1
              2,2
                2,3
                  2,4
      1,0
        1,1
          1,2
            1,3
              2,0
                2,1
                  2,2
                    2,3
                      2,4
            2,0
              2,1
                2,2
                  2,3
                    2,4
          2,0
            2,1
              2,2
                2,3
                  2,4
        2,0
          2,1
            2,2
              2,3
                2,4
    1,0
      1,1
        1,2
          1,3
            2,0
              2,1
                2,2
                  2,3
                    2,4
          2,0
            2,1
              2,2
                2,3
                  2,4
        2,0
          2,1
            2,2
              2,3
                2,4
      2,0
        2,1
          2,2
            2,3
              2,4
  1,0
    1,1
      1,2
        1,3
          2,0
            2,1
              2,2
                2,3
                  2,4
        2,0
          2,1
            2,2
              2,3
                2,4
      2,0
        2,1
          2,2
            2,3
              2,4
    2,0
      2,1
        2,2
          2,3
            2,4
```

Also, instead of pushing a result at the end of each range of `j` values, it will push a result for every single call.

Comment: Hey Guffa. my code did do exactly like the top box u posted and that is exactly what i wanted. the bug in the original problem was i didnt use return to call the recursion function again....it was ugly. when i put the keyword return as "return john(arr, i + 1, 0, total, coord)" it fix all the problem and got exactly as u mentioned in the top box of ur post. THANKS

Comment: @johnchau: That doesn't work, but using a return at the first recursive call works. However, it's not functional programming, as you are not using the return values from the recursive calls anywhere. You can just as well use `john(arr, i, j +1, total, coord); return coord;`: http://jsfiddle.net/9ccr2kbj/

Comment: for to whether or not it functional programming u talking about, you are right because i dont know the definition of functional programming. so i m sorry about that. by the way, if u can do write another code version that achieve the same goal, i like to see it. i m still a noob at programming.lol

Comment: @johnchau: The task simply doesn't lend itself well to a recursive solution. You will just end up simulating a loop, as there is no way to divide the work in a way that makes real use of recursion.

Comment: A better example would be if you instead had one large array of temperatures and wanted to find the highest. You could let the function split the array in two and call the function for each part. That would qickly divide the work in smaller and smaller parts until it was a matter of comparing just two values, which would be trivial. A good recursive algorithm turns complex work into trivial parts, and doesn't make deep chains of calls even for large quantities of data.

Answer (score -1):

/// recursion answer

```
function john( arr, i, j, total, coord)
{

   var total = total || 0;
   var coord = coord || [];

  if(i < arr.length)
  {

   if(j < arr[i].temperatures.length)
   {
     total = arr[i].temperatures[j] + total;
     john(arr, i, j + 1, total, coord)
   }

     ave = total / arr[i].temperatures.length;
     total = 0;
     coord.push([ave, arr[i].population])

     return john(arr, i + 1, 0, total, coord)

    }
    return return coord;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

/// recursion answer

```
function john( arr, i, j, total, coord)
{

   var total = total || 0;
   var coord = coord || [];

  if(i < arr.length)
  {

   if(j < arr[i].temperatures.length)
   {
     total = arr[i].temperatures[j] + total;
     john(arr, i, j + 1, total, coord)
   }

     ave = total / arr[i].temperatures.length;
     total = 0;
     coord.push([ave, arr[i].population])
     // it need return john(arr, i + 1, 0, total, coord)
     // cannot be john(arr, i+1, 0, total, coord)
     return john(arr, i + 1, 0, total, coord)

    }

    return coord;
  }
```